# How to grep a vector and return a single TRUE or FALSE?

Tags: regex, r

Is there a `grep` function in R that returns `TRUE` if a pattern is found anywhere in the given character vector and `FALSE` otherwise?

All the functions I see return a *vector* of the current positions of each element found.

Comment: Reading ?grep would be a good place to start

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are you looking for "any"?

```
> x<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
> x==5
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
> any(x==5)
[1] TRUE
```

Note that you can do this for strings as well

```
> x<-c("a","b","c","d")
> any(x=="b")
[1] TRUE
> any(x=="e")
[1] FALSE
```

And it can be convenient when combined with applies:

```
> sapply(c(2,4,6,8,10), function(x){ x%%2==0 }  )
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
> any(sapply(c(2,4,6,8,10), function(x){ x%%2!=0 }  ))
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Note that this approach only works for exact matching, while the OP's mention of `grep` suggests he is rather looking for a pattern matching. For exact matching, you can also use `is.element` and it is vectorized.

Answer (score 35):

possibly a combination of `grepl()` and `any()`?

like

```
> foo = c("hello", "world", "youve", "got", "mail")
> any(grepl("world", foo))
[1] TRUE
> any(grepl("hi", foo))
[1] FALSE  
> any(grepl("hel", foo))
[1] TRUE
```

your questions a little unclear as to whether you want that last example to return true or not

Answer (score 28):

Perhaps you're looking for `grepl()`?

```
> grepl("is", c("This", "is", "a", "test", "isn't", "it?"))
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Where the first argument is the pattern you're looking for, the second argument is the vector against which you want to match, and the returned value is a Boolean vector of the same length describing whether or not the pattern was matched to each element.

Comment: This is the only answer which actually answers the question.

Answer (score 5):

grepl is what you are looking for

```
grepl("is", "This is grepl test")
[1] TRUE
grepl("is not", "This is grepl test")
[1] FALSE
```