# Efficient pattern detecting in vector of strings

Tags: r, performance, pattern-matching, stringr

I'm looking for the most efficient solution to the problem posed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480950/how-to-grep-a-vector-and-return-a-single-true-or-false): Say you have a vector `v` of strings:

```r
set.seed(314159)
library(stringi)
library(stringr)

v <- stringi::stri_rand_strings(10000, 4, pattern = "[A-Z]")

head(v)
#> [1] "FQGK" "YNQH" "IMNJ" "WUFU" "BBAR" "BZUH"
```

I want to *efficiently* return a single logical representing whether a given pattern, say `"FOO"`, matches any of the strings in `v`. A prospective function would work like this:

```
detect("FOO")
#> FALSE
detect("BAR")
#> TRUE
```

There are several methods to do this with base `grep` functions or using `stringr::str_detect`, but these each involve first matching a regex on every element of `v`, doing up to 9,999 unnecessary tests in my example. An efficient solution would stop evaluation after a single match is found.

For each solution `detect.#`, I benchmark it by applying it to all three letter combinations `c`:

```r
c <- combn(LETTERS,3, FUN = function(x){paste(x, collapse = '')})
head(c)
#> [1] "ABC" "ABD" "ABE" "ABF" "ABG" "ABH"
```

### Possible Solutions

There are a few possible solutions that I have come up with. To start, looping over `v` so that unnecessary pattern matching isn't done after a match is found. As you'll see, this is a terrible idea with lots of overhead:

```r
detect.1 <- function(pattern){
  for (i in 1:length(v)){
    if (length(grep(pattern, v[i]))){return(TRUE)}
  }
  return(FALSE)
}
```

Next, we could use combinations of `any()` and `grepl()` or `stringr::str_detect()`, but then we do unnecessary match tests:

```r
#str_detect() from stringr
detect.2 <- function(pattern){
  any(str_detect(v, pattern) )
}

# any() and grepl()
detect.3 <- function(pattern){
  any(grepl(pattern, v))
}
```

Finally, *if* we know a character never appears in `pattern`, we can collapse `v` into a single string with components separated by this character. Then a single `grep` would suffice:

```r
#collapse to long string
v_pasted <- paste(v, collapse = '_')
detect.4 <- function(pattern){
  isTRUE(as.logical(grep(pattern, v_pasted)))
}
```

### Benchmarks

(updated to use `bench::mark()`)

```r
det1 <- expression(data.frame(c, "inV" = I(lapply(c, FUN = detect.1))))
det2 <- expression(data.frame(c, "inV" = I(lapply(c, FUN = detect.2))))
det3 <- expression(data.frame(c, "inV" = I(lapply(c, FUN = detect.3))))
det4 <- expression({
  v_pasted <- paste(v, collapse = '_')
  data.frame(c, "inV" = I(lapply(c, FUN = detect.4)))
})

bench::mark(
  eval(det1),
  eval(det2),
  eval(det3),
  eval(det4),
  iterations = 5,
  relative = TRUE
)
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is
#> disabled.
#> # A tibble: 4 x 10
#>   expression   min  mean median   max `itr/sec` mem_alloc  n_gc n_itr
#>   <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 eval(det1) 76.9  77.0   76.8  77.2        1        1      Inf     1
#> 2 eval(det2)  4.02  4.03   4.04  4.05      19.1    735.     Inf     1
#> 3 eval(det3)  2.77  2.79   2.79  2.80      27.6    735.     Inf     1
#> 4 eval(det4)  1     1      1     1         77.0      1.22   NaN     1
```

`grepl` is noticeably faster than `str_detect`. The pasting method is fastest, but requires you to have a separation character that doesn't appear in possible search patterns. Is there some faster alternative that I am missing?

Comment: Nice question, but I see a couple of problems right off the bat. First of all, I think you should try your benchmarks again (I got completely different results). Take a look at the packages `bench` or `microbenchmark`. Secondly, although negligible, you should probably include the pasting part inside `detect.4`.

Comment: @JosephWood, thanks for the feedback. I've updated with benchmarks using `bench`, and moved the paste statement withing the benchmarked expression as you suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function from `stringi` package should be faster:

```
any(stri_detect_fixed(v, pattern, max_count = 1))
```

bench:

```
require(stringi)
detect.m <- function(pattern){
  any(stri_detect_fixed(v, pattern, max_count = 1))
}

detm <- expression(data.frame(c, "inV" = I(lapply(c, FUN = detect.m))))
r <- bench::mark(
  # eval(det1),
  eval(det2),
  eval(det3),
  eval(det4),
  eval(detm),
  iterations = 5,
  relative = TRUE
)
r[, 1:10]
#   expression   min  mean median   max `itr/sec` mem_alloc  n_gc n_itr total_time
#    <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1 eval(det2)  4.83  5.39   5.02  5.94      1         600.     9     1       5.39
# 2 eval(det3)  3.85  3.69   3.80  3.31      1.46      600.    10     1       3.69
# 3 eval(det4)  1.35  1.32   1.36  1.20      4.08        1      1     1       1.32
# 4 eval(detm)  1     1      1     1         5.39      600.     9     1       1
```

### Larger benchmark

```
# lets create larger test case for better comparison:

a <- expand.grid(lapply(1:5, function(x) LETTERS))
a <- do.call(paste0, a)
f10 <- a[10] # lets search for 10th element
last <- a[length(a)] # and last
length(a)
length(unique(a))

v <- a

detm <- function(pattern){
  any(stri_detect_fixed(v, pattern, max_count = 1))
}

det4 <- function(pattern){
  # should include paste
  v_pasted <- paste(v, collapse = '_')
  # isTRUE(as.logical(grep(pattern, v_pasted)))
  isTRUE(grepl(pattern, v_pasted, fixed = T)) # faster
}

system.time(detm(last)) # 0.74
system.time(detm(f10)) #  0.33

system.time(det4(last)) # 3.38
system.time(det4(f10)) #  3.08
```

Comment: Interesting, my benchmarks have `det4` slightly edging out `detm` (1 : 1.09). I had looked at the detect functions in `stringi` but found their help texts somewhat cryptic.

Comment: @DanTan updated with larger benchmark. Are you using the latest `stringi` package version? `max_count` is new in the latest version...